# .htaccess mod rewrite works on WAMPP but not XAMPP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, xampp

I am trying to write my `.htaccess` file so that all pages of the website (index.php, sports.php, team.php and about.php) appear as `domain/index`. `team.php` also occasionally takes in a `$_GET` variable which i am trying to show as `domain/team/getvariable`. I have came up with the following .htacces:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

DirectoryIndex index.php team.php sports.php about.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]

#RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ ./team.php?s=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
```

This meets all my requirements on WAMPP, however hosting the website using XAMPP behaves differently; the redirection to `team/getvariable` succeeds but throws a 404 error, the rest of it works well. You can also see that I have tried this one with a different approach but it behaves the same way as the current line. What am I doing wrong?

**Solution** 
I changed the last line to 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ team.php?s=$1 [NC]`

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting `/team/variable` to `/team/variable.php`. I guess this occurs your 404 error.

So I think you want to rewrite to something like `/team.php?v=variable`? Then this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php?v=$2
```

Why it works on WAMPP is another question...

Comment: I want to rewrite `/team.php?s=variable` -> `/team/variable` unfortunately your solution also throws a 404 (after changing v to s)

Comment: I took the first part of the rule from your rule without checking it. It matches a url with ending slash. so `/team/variable/` should work. So simple remove the last / before the $ --> `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?v=$2`